# Deploy Grails app to AppFog using Eclipse CloudFoundry plugin

Tags: grails, cloud-foundry, appfog

I'm trying to deploy my Grails application to AppFog using CloudFoundry plugin (ver. 1.1) in Spring Source Suites (STS 2.9.2).
I'm using https://api.appfog.com as server address and MYAPPNAME.aws.af.cm for application address when deploying app.
Application is pushed and started, services are bounded but, after that, I recive error saying that: 
Communication with server failed: I/O error: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: https://api.appfog.com/apps/MYAPPNAME/application

Also, when I try to create Caldecott tunnel toward database I recive response "The URIs: caldecott-85393a.appfog.com have already been taken or reserved. (404 Not Found)" which I also saw when (by mistake) treid to deploy application to MYAPPNAME.api.appfog.com (default AF name instead of particular infrastructure adress).

I suppose that CloudFoundry plugin uses default server address to reach application and also trying to create Caldecott tunnel on default server address (caldecott-85393a.appfog.com instead of caldecott-85393a.aws.af.cm)

Does anybody have idea how to circumvent this situation?

BR
Zoran

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I successfully deployed to CF as well and can tunnel to my MySQL service without issue there but I get the same message as you when I attempt to tunnel to my AF MySQL service. I'm going to post to the discussion group there to see if I can get help. I searched and it doesn't look like there is a related question on there already.

Answer (score 1):

this doesn't sound like an issue with the plugin itself but the response coming back from AppFog's cloud. I would take this up as an issue with them and clarify you can use that plugin with their cloud.

Comment: At any case I will post query to both AppFog and CloudFoundry to see what can be done. From my point of view it seems that plugin also can be updated to fit various possible implementations usage of CloudFoundry.

Comment: I am part of the CloudFoundry support team. Have you tried getting an account on CloudFoundry.com and pushing there as well to see if you have the same issues?

Comment: Sorry, just minute ago I realized that you are from CloudFoundry :-) I probably forgot to mention, I deployed same app on CF without problems. I also deployed it to AF but, after deploy, plugin tries to get some information about app and then, by default, asking for it on MYAPP.appfog.com (application name + server address). Problem is that AF uses more than one infrastructure with different addresses and no deploys are allowed on main address(on CF everything goes to  cloudfoundry.com). I posted same question to AF support.

Answer (score 0):

AppFog had issues recently with their Java deployments that was specifically affecting Grails apps. This has been resolved and should be working seamlessly as expected now. You can always reach out for more information in the active google group as well: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/appfog-users